# How do we use more than one message in flashMessenger using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I am using zend. I have the following piece of code,

```
....
$cust = 'test@test.com';
$list.='Also Sent Mail to following members';
                foreach($m_list as $value)
                {
                $mail_to_manu = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');                    
                $mail_to_manu->clearFrom();                    
                $mail_to_manu->setBodyHtml('Text')
                ->setFrom('noreply@test.com', 'test admin')
                ->addTo($value['email'])
                ->setSubject('Test');
                $mail_to_manu->send();       
                $list.=$value['manufacturers_email'].'<br/>';
                } 
                $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Mail send to '. $cust. ' Successfully'.$list);
        $this->_redirector->gotoUrl('/index');    
.....
```

I got message with out any break.my message looks like,

```
Mail send to test@test.com Successfully Also Sent Mail to following members some1@example.com some2@example.com...
```

I need to my message will be like,

```
 Mail send to test@test.com Successfully 
 Also Sent Mail to following members,
 some1@example.com
 some2@example.com
 ...
```

So i need some break one after another.Is it possible to do that in Flash messenger. If yes,Kindly Advice.

Comment: Did none of these answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `strip_tags` or something similar in the view script? It could cause the `<br />` tags to get stripped out.

It's also possible to add multiple messages by calling `flashMessenger->addMessage()` once for every address:

```
$cust = 'test@test.com';
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Mail send to '. $cust. ' Successfully');
if(count($m_list)>0 )
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Also Sent Mail to following members');
foreach($m_list as $value)
{
    $mail_to_manu = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');                    
    $mail_to_manu->clearFrom();                    
    $mail_to_manu->setBodyHtml('Text')
    ->setFrom('noreply@test.com', 'test admin')
    ->addTo($value['email'])
    ->setSubject('Test');
    $mail_to_manu->send();       
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($value['manufacturers_email']);
} 
$this->_redirector->gotoUrl('/index');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. No i am not using any strip_tags.Also i tried using more than one flash messanger like you said but i got message with our break.

Comment: i use $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages(); in indexAction.
and use the following code to print the message
 <?php if (count($this->messages)) { ?>
<div class="w18" style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;width: 640px;color: #4B8109;">
<?php foreach ($this->messages as $message) { ?>
    <?php echo $this->escape($message); ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<!--

Comment: i got it by append break tag in template page <?php echo $this->escape($message).'<br/>'; ?>.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your question

The reason why it's all bunched up together is that you're `echo`ing it all out in a loop without additional markup.

What about something like:

```
foreach ($this->messages as $message)
{
    echo '<p class="message">' . $this->escape($message) . '</p>';
}
```

But, in fact, there is a much better way of handling the flashMessenger in views. As you know the Zend FlashMessenger is an action helper. But there is also a great view helper avaiable which helps you output your messages nicely. The best thing about it is, that you can pass an `array('warning' => 'This is a warning')` and the array key (warning) will be used as class for the `<p>` tag. You can find [information about this helper on Carlton Gibson's blog](http://blog.noumenal.co.uk/2009/08/using-zend-framework-flashmessenger.html) and [additional explanations in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739096/working-with-zend-framework-flashmessenger-and-jquery-ui-state-classes).

#### Your variable naming needs improvement

- Write readable variable names like `$customer` instead of just `$cust`. Nobody ever said shortening variable names is a means of writing lean code ;). Shortening variable names is bad (code smell) because it make code less readable for others and for yourself in the future.
- Use casing like this `$mailToManufacturer` instead of using underscores. It's a general agreement (standard) and therefore good for readability and understanding of code too.

Comment: Thanks, But i gave all varialble name just for example here